# How to check if path or file exist in Scala

Tags: scala

How do I check if a path / file exists in Scala similar to Python ? An example below:

```
os.path.exists("/home")
Out[4]: True
```

Answer (score 62, accepted):

Well, sorry I found the answer to my own question:

```
scala> new java.io.File("/tmp").exists
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Why does Files.exists(Paths.get("/tmp/subfolder")) give false when Files.exists(Paths.get("/tmp")) gives true?

Answer (score 131):

Since Java 7 the better way would be

```
scala> import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

scala> Files.exists(Paths.get("/tmp"))
res0: Boolean = true
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, how is this better?

Comment: @WalrustheCat, NIO.2 API is an intended replacement for deprecated old `File` API. So, first, you should prefer it because it will help old API to die. Second, NIO.2 is more powerful. For example, with this API you can choose how to treat symbolic links. Or you can check (with the same `Files.exists()` call) existence of a path in another file system (e.g. in zip archive).

Comment: @VladimirMatveev  Why does Files.exists(Paths.get("/tmp/subfolder")) give false when Files.exists(Paths.get("/tmp")) gives true?

Comment: @Innovator-programmer hard to tell without a broader context, but this seems to mean that you don't have the `subfolder` directory inside `/tmp`. I personally find this quite logical)

Comment: @VladimirMatveev: of course inside /tmp folder there is many nested folders, so I gave full path where I want to check if the files are present, but it gives me false . dont know why.

Answer (score 10):

It is an old question, but I still need it needs some update. You should use `isFile` or `isRegularFile` instead of `exists` since `exists` don´t take in account if is a File or a Directory and can mislead the application in case there is a directory with the same name.

Using java.io

```
new java.io.File("/tmp/sample.txt").isFile
```

Using java.nio

```
java.nio.file.Files.isRegularFile(java.nio.file.Paths.get("/tmp/sample.txt"))
```

Answer (score 5):

```
scala.reflect.io.File("/tmp/sample.txt").exists
```

works as well.