# Scala - reading to a DataFrame when a path to the file doesn't exist

Tags: scala, dataframe, apache-spark, amazon-s3, apache-spark-sql

I'm reading metrics data from json files from S3. What is the right way to handle the case when a path to the file doesn't exist? Currently I'm getting an `AnalysisException: Path does not exist` when there is no file with a given `$metricsData` name.

I think one way is to throw an exception but how should I correctly check if a path to the file exists?

```
val metricsDataDF: DataFrame = spark.read.option("multiline", "true")
        .json(s"$dataPath/$metricsData.json")
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I wouldn't use `java.nio.file`, it doesn't have a proper binding to S3 and/or HDFS. If you want your code to be applicable for all filesystems (local, in Docker (CI/CD), S3, HDFS, etc.) try using Apache Hadoop utils:

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration

val path = new Path("base/path/to/data")
val fs = path.getFileSystem(new Configuration())

// applicable for local and remote FS
if (fs.exists(path)) {
    sparkSession.read(...)
}
```

Comment: Can we be sure that it'll work once deployed? My app will run on a spark cluster in a cloud (azure) and access distributed fs (adfs) provided by my company. All these come with lots of security constraint. So, I will test it, but can I be confident that if spark can read the file, then hadoop.fs.Path will work?

Comment: Yes. Spark itself uses these same packages when it iterates on the designated filesystem and path (local, hdfs, s3, azure etc.).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.nio.file` :

```scala
import java.nio.file.{Paths, Files}

if(Files.exists(Paths.get(s"$dataPath/$metricsData.json")))
    val metricsDataDF: DataFrame = spark.read.option("multiline", "true")
        .json(s"$dataPath/$metricsData.json")
```

[How to check if path or file exist in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177107/how-to-check-if-path-or-file-exist-in-scala)