# show unavailable directory at compile time?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

In Spark Scala, usually one has to provide any source data reference as a path in String format, such as below:

```
val sourceRdd = sc.textFile("C:/Users/[myName]/Documents/Scala/UdemySparkScala/IDE-project-for-course/Resources/1800.csv")
```

As I actually like the idea of "failing fast", I was wondering if it's possible to somehow restructure this code, to already display an error at compile time, not just at run time.

Does scala have something like this? Maybe a library I can make use of?

Comment: How do you compile? SBT? Maven?

Comment: Usually I use sbt privately, and maven in a corporate environment, but in this specific case, it is an Intellij managed project. So not sure, what it chooses in the background.

Comment: Let's say I run a piece of code that you compiled. How do you know at compile time what files exist on my computer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to check at compile time whether a file exists you can try a [macro](https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/overview.html)

```
import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox

def checkFileExistsAtCompileTime(path: String): Unit = macro impl

def impl(c: blackbox.Context)(path: c.Tree): c.Tree = {
  import c.universe._
  val q"${pathStr: String}" = path
  if (scala.reflect.io.File(pathStr).exists)
    q"()"
  else c.abort(c.enclosingPosition, s"$pathStr doesn't exist")
}
```

Usage:

```
checkFileExistsAtCompileTime(".../myfile") // compiles
// checkFileExistsAtCompileTime(".../myfile1") // doesn't compile, .../myfile1 doesn't exist
```

[How to check if path or file exist in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21177107/how-to-check-if-path-or-file-exist-in-scala)

Comment: Thank you, I was having a look into it. But I don't understand this, as I am still fairly new to Scala and programming in general. Nonetheless I will try it out and see what happens.